# Merge sort in ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, mergesort

I am learning how to implement basic algorithms in Java, so i am a newbie in this environment. I am trying to implement Merge Sort algorithm using ArrayList where program will read data (Integer in each line) from file and produce sorting result using Merge Sort. However, my code is showing same result as it has not sorted anything out! I would be very glad if someone can identify where did I do my mistake. As i am a beginner, the code is very simple, not optimized and not very fast in performance probably.

Here is my code:

```
public class MergeSortExp1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer>number = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Scanner myScanner = null;
        try {
        myScanner = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Sabbir/Desktop/workload.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(myScanner.hasNextInt()){
            number.add(myScanner.nextInt());
        }

        System.out.println("Before sorting" +number);
        number=mergeSort(number);
        System.out.println("Sorted Array =" +number);
    }

        public static ArrayList<Integer> mergeSort( ArrayList<Integer> Input)
        {
            if (Input.size() ==1){
                return Input;
            }
            else {
                int mid= Input.size()/2;
                ArrayList<Integer> left= new ArrayList<Integer>(mid);
                ArrayList<Integer> right=new ArrayList<Integer>(Input.size()-mid);

               for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
                   left.add(Input.get(i));
                   } 

               for (int i = 0; i < Input.size()-mid; i++) {
                   right.add(Input.get(i));
               } 

               left=mergeSort(left); 
               right=mergeSort(right);
               merge(left,right,Input);
            }
               return Input;
        }


        public static void merge (ArrayList<Integer>left,ArrayList<Integer>right,ArrayList<Integer>Input)
        {
            int i1=0;// left Index
            int i2=0;// right Index
            int InputIndex=0;

            for (int i = 0; i < Input.size(); i++) {
                if (i2>=right.size() || (i1<left.size() && left.get(i)<=right.get(i))) 
                {
                    Input.set(InputIndex,left.get(i1));
                    InputIndex++;
                }
                else {
                    Input.set(InputIndex, right.get(i2));
                    InputIndex++;
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: from where you are calling `merge ` method??

Comment: oh How silly I am? I should call merge(left, right, Input) after calling the recursive method!    left=mergeSort(left); right=mergeSort(right); merge(left, right, Input);   right?

Answer (score 0):

If your merge method is Ok (I don't test it), you forget to merge left and right to input, edit your code as shown below and re-try:

```
 // This is called recursion. Calling a method again within the  
 //method until the value of left and right becomes 1.
 left=mergeSort(left); 
 right=mergeSort(right);

 merge(left,right,Input);
```

hope helped you!

Comment: I am getting some error now. like :                                         Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
 at Sort.MergeSortExp1.merge(MergeSortExp1.java:66)
 at Sort.MergeSortExp1.mergeSort(MergeSortExp1.java:53)
 at Sort.MergeSortExp1.mergeSort(MergeSortExp1.java:51)
 at Sort.MergeSortExp1.mergeSort(MergeSortExp1.java:51)
 at Sort.MergeSortExp1.main(MergeSortExp1.java:28)

Comment: Could you explain, where did i do the mistake please?

Comment: Well, the problem is solved and everything is working. Thanks to all who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

One more variant:

```
    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> mergeSort(List<T> unsortedList) {
    if (unsortedList.size() <= 1) {
        return unsortedList;
    }
    List<T> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(unsortedList.size());
    List<T> leftList = mergeSort(unsortedList.subList(0, unsortedList.size() / 2));
    List<T> rightList = mergeSort(unsortedList.subList(unsortedList.size() / 2, unsortedList.size()));
    int leftIdx = 0;
    int rightIdx = 0;
    int resultIdx = 0;
    while (leftIdx < leftList.size() && rightIdx < rightList.size()) {
        if (leftList.get(leftIdx).compareTo(rightList.get(rightIdx)) <= 0) {
            sortedList.add(resultIdx, leftList.get(leftIdx));
            leftIdx++;
        } else {
            sortedList.add(resultIdx, rightList.get(rightIdx));
            rightIdx++;
        }
        resultIdx++;
    }
    while (leftIdx < leftList.size()) {
        sortedList.add(resultIdx, leftList.get(leftIdx));
        leftIdx++;
        resultIdx++;
    }
    while (rightIdx < rightList.size()) {
        sortedList.add(resultIdx, rightList.get(rightIdx));
        rightIdx++;
        resultIdx++;
    }
    return sortedList;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Mergesort1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int zeilen = 0;

        try{
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                values.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
                zeilen++;
            }
            try{  
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));

                sort(values); //sortien array list
                for (int i=0; i<values.size(); i++){
                    writer.write("" + values.get(i));
                    writer.newLine();
                }
                writer.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
      public static ArrayList<Integer> sort( ArrayList<Integer> values)
        {
            if (values.size() ==1){
                return values;
            }
            else {
                int mid= values.size()/2;
                ArrayList<Integer> left= new ArrayList<Integer>(mid);
                ArrayList<Integer> right=new ArrayList<Integer>(values.size()-mid);

               for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
                   left.add(values.get(i));
                   } 

               for (int i = mid; i < values.size(); i++) {
                   right.add(values.get(i));
               } 

               left=sort(left); 
               right=sort(right);
               merge(left,right,values);
            }
               return values;
        }


        public static void merge (ArrayList<Integer>left,ArrayList<Integer>right,ArrayList<Integer>values)
        {
            int i1=0;// left Index
            int i2=0;// right Index
            int InputIndex=0;



            for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {

                if(i1==left.size()){
                    values.set(i, right.get(i2));
                    i2++;
                }
                else{
                    if (i2==right.size()){
                        values.set(i,left.get(i1));
                        i1++;
                    }
                    else{
                        if (left.get(i1)<=right.get(i2)) {
                            values.set(i,left.get(i1));
                            i1++;
                        }
                        else {
                            if (left.get(i1)>=right.get(i2)) {
                            values.set(i, right.get(i2));
                            i2++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
}
```